# How to find out the log file name that a currently running process is writing to?

Tags: linux, centos, command-line-interface, redhat

We've setup a cron-based invocation of a Java program every minute. This Java program invocation is written in a shell script and is setup as *cron* job.  Each invoked Java program is directed to its own separate log file (using date & time as file name with precision upto minutes) as shown below:

**calljavaprogram.sh**

```
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M`
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0/bin/java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError MyJavaProgram 2>&1 >> $DATE.log | tee -a $DATE.err >> $DATE.log &
```

For example, I can find out the currently running Java process (MyJavaProgram) at any time using the following command:

```
[root@user ~]# ps -ef |grep MyJavaProgram
user    4321     1  0 Oct17 ?        00:00:17 /usr/java/jdk1.6.0/bin/java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError MyJavaProgram
user    5747     1  0 Oct17 ?        00:00:11 /usr/java/jdk1.6.0/bin/java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError MyJavaProgram
```

My question is, I want to find out the actual log file name to which the *currently executing* Java process (MyJavaProgram) is writing to. So, for example, if there are 2 `MyJavaProgram` currently executing, I want to know the log file name of each process.  In this case, I'm interested/want to know the `.log` extension file, though there are 2 extensions - `.log` and `.err`.

**NOTE:** Log file name is generated in this pattern, `2011-10-17_19-28.log`, for example.  Our server is RHEL4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command "lsof" might help you out here.

```
lsof | grep $PID |grep .log
```

or similar should yield you with a list of files that process is accessing.

Comment: Another way of doing the same thing is `ls -l /proc/$PID/fd/*.log`

You can also make the above command more efficient by using `lsof -p $PID | grep '\.log'`

Comment: @Antitribu: If there are multiple `MyJavaProgram` Java process currently running, how do I pass PID dynamically to `lsof` command?

Comment: @Gnanam , you mean something like `for i in \`ps aux |grep java |grep -v grep |awk '{print $2}'\`; do echo $i; lsof |grep $i |grep \.log; done` ? Flavor to taste

Comment: @Antitribu: Actually, I didn't intend to mean/ask anything specifically, but I'm just trying to find out whether multiple $PID can be passed dynamically to `lsof` command.

Comment: @Gnanam all good, lsof just gives you a list of open files that you can parse any way you wish.